# I want to develop kendo UI listview with endless scroll . Can anyone suggeset me the references

Tags: angularjs, listview, kendo-ui

I want to develop Kendo UI List view with endless scroll, please suggest me the solutions. or references

Answer (score 0):

First, take the pagesize off your datasource. Second, don't use a pager control. Here is an example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/OLUFA

See the api [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listview).

Comment: Hi steve can look the below code where there is no endless scroll option is there, i want to covert it into endless scroll i am copying the current code..